# How to get a path from one node to another including all other nodes and relationships involved in between

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, path-finding

I have designed a model in Neo4j in order to get paths from one station to another including platforms/legs involved. The model is depicted down here. Basically, I need a query to take me from NBW to RD. also shows the platforms and legs involved. I am struggling with the query. I get no result. Appreciate if someone helps.

Here is my cypher statement:

```
MATCH p = (a:Station)-[r:Goto|can_board|can_alight|has_platfrom*0..]->(c:Station)
WHERE (a.name='NBW') 
AND c.name='RD' 
RETURN p
```

Model:
[image]

Comment: If you remove the relationship types from the query do you get a result? If so, can you add them back in one at a time until you stop getting a result?

Comment: No, I am not getting any result.  I think the issue is because there is no relationship between those two red circles(stations) and I am matching by them !?

Comment: ahh, i see the problem, your query is directed. take off the direction in the query

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want it to be directed?

Comment: then you need to have all of the paths in your model heading in that direction. you would probably end up doubling up on relationships between your nodes if you needed to be able to query in both directions. i guess ultimately it depends on your model.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, in Cypher you can't use a directed variable-length relationship that uses differing directions for some of the relationships.

However, [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) just added the ability to expand based on sequences of relationships. You can give this a try:

```
MATCH (start:station), (end:station)
WHERE start.name='NBW' AND end.name='THT'
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(start, {terminatorNodes:[end], limit:1,
  relationshipFilter:'has_platform>, can_board>, goto>, can_alight>, <has_platform'}) YIELD path
RETURN path
```

I added a limit so that only the first (and shortest) path to your end station will be returned. Removing the limit isn't advisable, since this will continue to repeat the relationships in the expansion, going from station to station, until it finds all possible ways to get to your end station, which could hang your query.

EDIT

Regarding the new model changes, the reason the above will not work is because relationship sequences can't contain a variable-length sequence within them. You have 2 `goto>` relationships to traverse, but only one is specified in the sequence.

Here's an alternative that doesn't use sequences, just a whitelisting of allowed relationships. The `spanningTree()` procedure uses NODE_GLOBAL uniqueness so there will only be a single unique path to each node found (paths will not backtrack or revisit previously-visited nodes).

```
MATCH (start:station), (end:station)
WHERE start.name='NBW' AND end.name='RD'
CALL apoc.path.spanningTree(start, {terminatorNodes:[end], limit:1,
  relationshipFilter:'has_platform>|can_board>|goto>|can_alight>|<has_platform'}) YIELD path
RETURN path
```

Comment: If you need multiple paths (don't want to use `limit`), but don't want the query to hang, you might want to add `maxLevel`, and set that to a multiple of the expected hops to reach the end station (5, in this case)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I updated my model and added a new station called "RD" to test the above query. It works only from "NBW" to "THT" but not from "NBW" to "RD". As you see in the updated image above.  Not sure what else is missing?                                                                                  ------------------------------MATCH (start:station), (end:station)
WHERE start.name='NBW' AND end.name='RD'
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(start, {terminatorNodes:[end],
  relationshipFilter:'has_platform>, can_board>, goto>, can_alight>, <has_platform'}) YIELD path
RETURN path

Comment: Hi, Now it is not working in any way. Even not working from "NBW" to "THT" which was working before.

Comment: This was a problem of changing case. In your first image, you had `:Station` nodes and you had a `:Goto` relationship, all other node labels and relationship types were lowercase. In your new image (and graph data), you changed to using lowercase `:station` labels and `:goto` relationship. Neo4j is case sensitive, you need to keep your cases consistent.

Comment: Absolutely true. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more question, please. Is it possible to add one more condition to say only return the path if an attribute inside a leg(yellow circle) of the start node is for example equal to 1?

Comment: Just the very first :leg node associated with your starting station? Or all :leg nodes encountered during expansion?

Comment: Probably best to match to the leg node first, then use a WHERE clause to ensure your condition, then do the path expander call. If the predicate fails, then there will be no rows for the procedure to operate on, and you won't get anything returned.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is directed `-->` and not all of the relationships between your two stations run in the same direction. If you remove the relationship direction you will get a result.

Then once you have a result I think something like this could get you pointed in the right direction on extracting the particular details from the resulting path once you get that working.

Essentially I am assuming that everything you are interested in is in your path that is returned you just need to filter out the different pieces that are returned.

As @InverseFalcon points out this query should be limited in a larger graph or it could easily run away.

```
MATCH p = (a:Station)-[r:Goto|can_board|can_alight|has_platfrom*0..]-(c:Station) 
WHERE (a.name='NBW') 
AND c.name='THT' 
RETURN filter( n in nodes(p) WHERE 'Platform' in labels(n)) AS Platforms
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when there is no relation between those two red circles (station), how should the query return a result?

Comment: Careful with that query, as the results are not limited, this could hang on a larger graph